# Unprojecting a screen point to a horizontal plane in ARKit

Tags: matrix, opengl-es, augmented-reality, arkit, metal

I'm trying to unproject some point on the screen to a coordinate on an ARPlaneAnchor in world space using ARKit. Essentially I want to draw a marker on the ground plane based on where my camera is pointing. ARKit provides some methods to do this, however they are attached to the ARCamera class, and unfortunately in my scenario I only have access to the camera's projection, view, and transform matrices and have no reference to the ARFrame or ARCamera objects themselves. I've written something similar (as far as I can tell) to gluUnproject().

```
func screenToWorld(screenPoint: CGPoint, depth: Float, screenSize: CGSize, projectionMatrix: simd_float4x4, viewMatrix:simd_float4x4) -> float3{

    let viewProj = viewMatrix * projectionMatrix
    let inverse = simd_inverse(viewProj)

    let x = (2.0 * screenPoint.x ) / screenSize.width - 1.0
    let y = (2.0 * screenPoint.y) / screenSize.height - 1.0

    let inPoint = float4(Float(x), Float(y), depth * 2.0 - 1.0, 1.0)

    var position = inPoint * inverse
    position.w = 1.0 / position.w

    position.x *= position.w
    position.y *= position.w
    position.z *= position.w

    return float3(position.x, position.y, position.z)
}


let pos = screenToWorld(screenPoint: CGPoint(360, 640), depth: depthBufferValue, screenSize: CGSize(720, 1280), projectionMatrix: projectionMatrix, viewMatrix: viewMatrix)
```

1. screenPoint is some window coordinate
2. depth is calculated by reading back a value from a depth buffer in an earlier pass
3. screenSize is the size of the viewport
4. projectionMatrix comes from [`projectionMatrix(for:.portrait, viewportSize: CGSize(720,1280),zNear: 0.001, zFar: 1000)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2923539-projectionmatrix)
5. viewMatrix comes from [`viewMatrix(for:.portrait)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2921672-viewmatrix)

The only one I'm not really sure of is the viewMatrix property. The only other thing I could think of that it could be would be the transform matrix attached to the camera. However, I've tried this and it also doesn't seem to give me the correct position. In gluUnproject they call this value the modelView matrix, in glm it is just called model, so I'm a little confused about what this is supposed to be.

With the value I get from my unProject function I translate an identity matrix like so

```
var modelMatrix = matrix_identity_float4x4
modelMatrix = modelMatrix.translatedBy(x: pos.x, y: pos.y, z: pos.z)
```

And then the values are sent to the shader like so...

```
encoder.setVertexBytes(&projectionMatrix, length: MemoryLayout<simd_float4x4>.stride, index: 1)
encoder.setVertexBytes(&viewMatrix, length: MemoryLayout<simd_float4x4>.stride, index: 2)
encoder.setVertexBytes(&modelMatrix, length: MemoryLayout<simd_float4x4>.stride, index: 3)
```

Inside of my vertex shader I do

```
VertexOut vertexOut;
float4x4 modelViewMatrix = viewMatrix * modelMatrix;
vertexOut.position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vertexIn.position;
return vertexOut;
```

I think my z value is correct (the depth value from the depth buffer), so really I just need to find my x and y. I'm also not 100% sure what to do with the value returned by my unproject function. I assume that is just the world coordinate but perhaps it needs to be scaled in some way?

I'd love some help getting the correct coordinate or if there are any mistakes in the above please point them out!

Comment: It has to be `viewProj = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix` and `position = inverse * inPoint`

Comment: Aha! I think that did the trick. It hurts to be so close and yet...

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who runs across this in the future, the solution (as suggested by @rabbid76) was flipping the order of multiplication of my projection and view matrices, as well as my inverse matrix and the inPoint. I also needed to flip the y coord of the screenPoint I wanted to check.

Here's the complete function:

```
func screenToWorld(screenPoint: CGPoint, depth: Float, screenSize: CGSize, projectionMatrix: simd_float4x4, viewMatrix:simd_float4x4) -> float3{

    let viewProj = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix
    let inverse = simd_inverse(viewProj)

    let x = (2.0 * screenPoint.x ) / screenSize.width - 1.0
    let y = 1.0 - (2.0 * screenPoint.y) / screenSize.height 

    let inPoint = float4(Float(x), Float(y), depth * 2.0 - 1.0, 1.0)

    var position = inverse * inPoint
    position.w = 1.0 / position.w

    position.x *= position.w
    position.y *= position.w
    position.z *= position.w

    return float3(position.x, position.y, position.z)
}
```

Comment: Does not work for me, will revert back if I find why